# finding the index of specific character in a string in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Write the the generic query for the given problem in  PostgreSQL format?

```
"901241,924685,924692,924670."
"901067,901069,901071,901071,901168,901168,901886,901891."
"PA,QW,NA,NS,0P,9P,NY,NY.N05-NH,NG,NC,NF.RI8-05,08,13,16."
"KC,K9,LA,L2.N05-K0,K1,K3,K6,K8,KE,LS,LZ,LU.RI8-05,08,13,16."
```

how can I write the generic query for above strings in this format in PostgreSQL:

```
(BETWEEN PA AND OW) AND (BETWEEN NA AND NS)........
(BETWEEN 901241 AND 924685) AND (BETWEEN 924692 AND 924679)
```

So far i tried:

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN SUBSTRING (gl_in2, 1, 1) = 'R'
          THEN
                '_'
             || SUBSTRING (gl_in2, 2, 2)
             || ' BETWEEN '
             || SUBSTRING (gl_in2, 5, POSITION (',' IN gl_in2) - 5)
             || ' AND '
             || SUBSTRING (gl_in2,
                           POSITION (',' IN gl_in2) + 1,
                           POSITION (',' IN gl_in2) - 5)
          ELSE
             NULL
       END
  FROM updatenew RESULT
 "_BC (BETWEEN 902103 AND 902136) AND
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please provide examples.  Please detail how the data relates to each other?  Please outline what sort of "generic query" you would like - are user-defined function allowed?

Comment: so far i tried

SELECT CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(gl_in2,1,1)='R' THEN '_'|| SUBSTRING(gl_in2,2,2)||' BETWEEN '||SUBSTRING(gl_in2,5,POSITION(',' in gl_in2)-5)||' AND ' ||SUBSTRING(gl_in2,POSITION(',' in gl_in2)+1,POSITION(',' in gl_in2)-5 ) ELSE NULL END FROM updatenew

RESULT

"_BC (BETWEEN 902103 AND 902136) AND

Answer (score 0):

Add table codes

```
CREATE TABLE "codes"(
 "id" Serial NOT NULL,
 "code" Character varying(50),
 "order_1" Integer
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE)
; 

ALTER TABLE "codes" ADD CONSTRAINT "PK_codes" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
;

ALTER TABLE "codes" ADD CONSTRAINT "order_1_unique" UNIQUE ("order_1")
;

ALTER TABLE "codes" ADD CONSTRAINT "code_unique" UNIQUE ("code")
;
```

Store this codes in table proposed above. 
Connect to codes table using PK/FK. 
Use between on order_1 column (You can add more orders rules - by adding new columns)

Comment: how we do this work using loop and by using split_part function